# median() returns 0 when used with tapply()

Tags: r, median, tapply

I have a dataframe `D` like this:

```
Number         Date Number2
     0   2015-11-01    1123
     4   2015-11-01    1175
    50   2015-11-01    1139
   122   2015-11-02    1105
    45   2015-11-02    1143
    99   2015-11-02    1123
```

of course, it has many more observations (around 17000), and some are NA. The column `Date` is a factor. I want to calculate the median of the column `Number` **by day** (using the column `Date`), for this i use the tapply function, like this:

```
tapply(D$Number, D$Date, median)
```

this outputs something like this:

```
2012-10-01 2012-10-02 2012-10-03 2012-10-04 2012-10-05 2012-10-06 
        NA          0          0          0          0          0        
2012-10-12 2012-10-13 2012-10-14 2012-10-15 2012-10-16 2012-10-17 
         0          0          0          0          0          0
2012-10-23 2012-10-24 2012-10-25 2012-10-26 2012-10-27 2012-10-28
         0          0          0          0          0         NA
```

This is the problem, why the zeros? I've already calculated the `sum` and the `mean` in the same way and it works perfectly, but when i try for the median all the calculations result in 0 or NA, even if i add `na.rm = TRUE` to the `tapply` function the result is the same. I really don't understand why this.

If i subset the dataframe "manually" (like `D[D$Date=='2012-10-01', 1]`) and apply the median function to that subset i get the correct result; however, I don't want to do this given the size of the dataframe.

Could somebody explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It works fine for the data you show there.  Can you show a few lines from the October data?